# Set Render Target usage

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, directx, glsl, shader

I am using Unity and I have some difficulties about understanding the way Set Render Target works and how it can behave with the shaders.

Is it possible to render a shader pass in multiple render targets ? How ?
As this behaviour seems to be linked with all rendering platforms and not only Unity, any help is welcome.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The [Graphics.SetRenderTarget](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.SetRenderTarget.html) overload that takes an array of `RenderBuffers` can be used to specify multiple render buffers. The shader can output multiple color values that will be written to those render buffers.

You can also query the maximum number of simultaneous supported render targets using [SystemInfo.supportedRenderTargetCount](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportedRenderTargetCount.html) in order to support system specific behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any implementation example ? Because I have some difficulties to make it work.